# Scrapy run javascript script in specific parse

Tags: javascript, python, scrapy, splash-screen

I'm recently starting using scrapy, and when i crawl a page,i have the problem of the currency that is showed. This is the part of the page that i need to click to change the actual currency: 
[image: Change currency]

I can do the same, but using the next script of javascript:
    setCurrency(1)
And i have to do this in all the pages, to make sure that every product uses the same currency. From what i've read, i can use splash with scrapy to do this, but, and correct me if i am wrong, but the code runs only one time with the constructor of the spider. 
Is there a way to run this only on the parse that extracts the product?. My code is like this now:

```
def parse(self, response):
    rutas = response.xpath("//a[@class='nonblock nontext rounded-corners rgba-background clip_frame grpelem']/@href").extract()
    for ruta in rutas:
        ruta_abs = response.urljoin(ruta)
        yield scrapy.Request(url=ruta_abs, callback=self.parse_producto)

def parse_producto(self, response):
    #Se debe ejecutar antes un script para cambiar la divisa
    nombre = response.xpath("//h1/text()").extract_first()
    #También conocido como "Referencia" por la página:
    codigo = response.xpath("//p[@id='product_reference']/span/text()").extract_first()
    descripcion = response.xpath("//div[@id='short_description_block']/div/p/text()").extract_first()
    url_foto = response.xpath("//div[@id='image-block']/span/img/@src").extract_first()
    precio = '.'.join(response.xpath("//span[@id='our_price_display']/text()").re(r"\d+"))
    categorias = response.xpath("//span[@class='navigation_page']/span/a/span/text()").extract()
    categoria_actual = ''
    num_categorias = len(categorias)
    if num_categorias > 1:
        num_categorias = (num_categorias-1)*-1
        categoria_actual = categorias[num_categorias]
    url_producto = response.url
    caract = response.xpath("//section[@class='page-product-box']/table[@class='table-data-sheet']/tr/td/text()").extract()
    ficha_tecnica = []
    if len(caract) > 1:
        ficha_tecnica = list(zip(caract[0::2],caract[1::2]))
    #Genero objeto producto:
    producto = Producto_tienda()
    producto['nombre'] = nombre
    producto['descripcion'] = descripcion
    producto['url_foto'] = url_foto
    producto['precio'] = precio
    producto['id_tienda'] = 2
    producto['tienda'] = 'ARTEC'
    producto['url_producto'] = url_producto
    producto['codigo'] = codigo
    producto['categoria'] = categoria_actual
    producto['ficha_tecnica'] = ficha_tecnica
    yield producto
```

I ommited the beggining of the code, where you set the name, allowed domains and start_urls to avoid legal issues.

I need to execute the javascript code everytime the spider is crawling the parse_producto function. Is there a way to do it?. If you need more information, i can give it you.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could use selenium + phantomJS and a DownloaderMiddleware
Here is a snippet from a [quick crawler](https://github.com/hcoura/google_crawler) I wrote for crawling google. You could do all you have to do here(like clicking on the currency button) before returning the HtmlResponse with the driver page_source.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
from scrapy.exceptions import IgnoreRequest
import time


class SeleniumMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        self.driver.get(request.url)
        try:
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "r")))
            body = self.driver.page_source
            return HtmlResponse(self.driver.current_url, body=body, encoding='utf-8', request=request)
        except Exception as e:
            # Timeout on WebDriverWait
            raise IgnoreRequest
```

You also need to set the DownloaderMiddleware in settings.py, for example:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'selenium_downloader_middleware.middlewares.SeleniumMiddleware': 723,
}
```